# TypoScript applicationContext condition with wildcards or sub-contexts not possible

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

Since TYPO3 9.5 LTS suggests to use the Symfony Expression Language for TypoScript conditions.

#### I have some troubles migrating them:

*Old Syntax:*

```
// Matches any applicationContext with a rootContext of "Production", for example "Production/Live" or "Production/Staging":
[applicationContext = Development*]

// Matches any applicationContext starting with "Production/Dev"
[applicationContext = /^Production\/Dev/]
```

#### to the new expression language:

*I've tried the following without success:*

```
[applicationContext == "/^Development\/Docker/"]

[applicationContext == "Development*"]

[applicationContext == "Development/*"]
```

---

I didn't found any examples. I'm not sure, if the tests for conditions are already based on the expression language. (https://review.typo3.org/#/c/57787/)

**Would be nice if someone has an advice how to use the feature to add conditions like before**

Comment: Does [The Expression Syntax](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#comparison-operators) help?

Comment: Thanks @MathiasBrodala for the hint.

With you info, the following can be done:
`[applicationContext matches "/^Development/"]` which matches when the actual Context is `Development/Docker`

Comment: It's much easier by using different regex delimiter like in my answer further down.

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable, thanks for having another look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [`matches` comparison operator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#comparison-operators) of the Symfony Expression Language. This way you can use regular expressions for partial matches:

```
[applicationContext matches "/^Development/"]
```

This will match any `Development` context.

Answer (score 7):

#### The following condition matches any applicationContext starting with "`Production/Dev`"

```
[applicationContext matches '/^Production\\\\\\\\/Dev/']
```

> **Why so many backslashes?** A backslash (`\`) must be escaped by 4 backslashes (`\\\\`) in a string and 8 backslashes (`\\\\\\\\`) in a regex in the Symfony Expression Language
>
> *([Symfony Expression Language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html) acts as the base for TypoScript conditions since TYPO3 9 LTS)*

---

> ### EDIT 2020-02: Using a different regex delimiter makes the readability much better for applicationContext conditions within TYPO3:
>
> Instead of `/` we can use `#` as regular expression delimiters.
>
> Here are some examples:

#### Match the "`Development`" applicationContext

```
[applicationContext matches "#^Development#"]
```

#### Match an applicationContext starting with "`Production/Dev`"

```
[applicationContext matches "#^Production/Dev#"]
```

#### Match an applicationContext starting with "`Production/Dev` or `Production/Staging`"

```
[applicationContext matches "#^Production/(Dev|Staging)#"]
```

#### Match an applicationContext starting with "`Production/Live`

```
[applicationContext matches "#^Production/Live#"]
```

#### Match an applicationContext starting with "`Production/Live` and an active TYPO3 backend user session

```
[applicationContext matches "#^Production/Live#" && getTSFE().isBackendUserLoggedIn()]
```

#### Match any applicationContext except those starting with "`Production`"

```
[not (applicationContext matches "#Production#")]
```

#### Match an applicationContext with exactly the value "`Production/Live/ClusterServer1`"

```
[applicationContext == "Production/Live/ClusterServer1"]
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer: please leave a comment. My answer is a valid solution based on the implementation in TYPO3 9 LTS. I want to know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Had issues updating my old conditions. Using another delimiter helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

This regexp matches the exact string "Production" and any string that starts with "Production/", eg "Production/Staging".

**Match an applicationContext is "Production" or is starting with "Production/"**

```
[applicationContext matches '#^Production(/|$)#']
```

Comment: It's not the same.

Comment: My regexp matches the exact string "Production" and any string that starts with "Production/", eg "Production/Staging". None of Josef's examples does that.

Comment: But as in TYPO3 there cannot be a context like "Productions" the regexp could be simpler as in Mathias' answer.

Answer (score -3):

In TYPO3 9 you can do `[applicationContext = Development/*]`

Comment: Sorry, but the "old" condition style is deprecated within TYPO3 9 LTS. Beside this, if you want to use the old conditions you HAVE TO disable the feature flag for the old TypoScript conditions.